# OpenShift oc new-app --docker-image=<podman img created from Dockerfile> - image not found/visible

Tags: openshift, podman

I've created an image with `podman build`, the image exists locally, I did not push it to any registry.
Now I am trying to create a new app with `oc new-app --docker-image=theimage --name=myapp` but it does not find the image.

How can I make it visible to `oc`?

Answer (score 0):

So, after some research and tries I found the next option:

1. Get the local openShift registry with `oc registry info`;
2. Log in:

   ```
   podman login -u `oc whoami` -p `oc whoami --show-token` `oc registry info`
   ```
3. Create an empty image stream:

   ```
   oc create imagestream yourimgname
   ```
4. Tag the local image you wish to push with the details of the **image registry**, **your project in OpenShift**, **the name of the image stream** and image version tag

   ```
    podman tag yourlocalimage `oc registry info`/openshiftproject/imagestreamname:latest
   ```
5. Push the image to the OpenShift registry

   ```
    podman push `oc registry info`/openshiftproject/imagestreamname
   ```